# How to override dispatchTouchEvent in AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have this dialog.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AppTheme_AlertDialog_SettingsConfirm)
            .setTitle(dialogVo.title)
            .setMessage(dialogVo.message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton(
                dialogVo.messageOnNegativeBtn,
                dialogVo.onNegativeClickListener
            )
            .setPositiveButton(
                dialogVo.messageOnPositiveBtn,
                dialogVo.onPositiveClickListener
            )
            .create()
```

How to override dispatchTouchEvent?

Comment: Can you explain what is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AlertDialog.Builder, use AlertDialog:

```
val alertDialog =object: AlertDialog(this,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle) {
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ///TODO
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }

}
```